# Working with two assets directories in Scala Play framework 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying to use 2 public assets routes. One for development version and the other one for production version. But this routes config does not work: for both pathes I receive 404 error.

```
GET  /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET  /us/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/us", file)
```

For the old play 2.0 I have to config extra assets directories in build.sbt

```
playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "us"
```

to publish all files in copiled target. But now this property does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been changed in Play 2.3 and there's [a migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration23#sbt-web) for this issue. Instead:

```
playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "us"
```

you should now use the following construction:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "us"
```

However, this will copy the content of `us` directory into `public` in the target distribution, so make sure you don't override something important. You can find more details in the given docs.

Comment: It works. But seems its better to use anyway just one public folder with subfolters - because during the build they anyway will be merged. The first my idea was to use one folder only for dev version. I am using grunt builder for static things - for development i am just making includes from bower and node component without its minification but in production i should have only one min.js file. But if my "us" dir will be anyway copied ( with a huge amount of included lib dirs ) it does not help .